# When I work calves in the gym, my feet hurt after the 10th or 15th rep

Tags: exercise, pain, legs

Is this just a starting thing? I have just started working calves.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly, yes. Certainly if you start an exercise, after a certain number of reps you will start feeling pain. However that's not the only reason to be feeling pain, there could be some muscular dysfunction, but that's not something anyone could determine over the internet.

I would suggest scaling back the reps for a while, if you start feeling pain after the 10th, then stop at just 8 for the next few weeks, then slowly creep back up and see if the pain comes back. If the pain starts manifesting even with lower reps, then perhaps you should see a doctor.

Comment: Cheers guys. I have been working my calves a bit more consistently and they pain is getting a bit better each time. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

I think more information would be helpful, where does it hurt and what exercise(s) are you performing.  Pain is your body's way of saying 'stop' that you are proceeding to do something that will potentially cause short (or long) term damage - dependent on the level of pain, your natural pain threshold and where the pain is.  A LOT OF TIME pain is an indication that you are performing the exercise incorrectly - so, be careful and get help/advice prior to proceeding.  Ligament-strains, tendons-tears and bone-stress-factures are common for people new to exercise and could stop short any continued progress.

Comment: x2. It could be muscular, tendon or bone and you have no way of knowing. One of the things that's a flag is that the Achilles tendon runs along the back of the heel and inserts (I think that's right, I always get insertion and origin mixed up) on the bottom of the foot, which given that it anchors the calf muscles and you are working the calves could be a big warning flag. Trust me (still have cast from surgery) you DO NOT want an achilles tendon rupture. Pain is also a funny thing, it can get referred from other places, so where you feel it may not actually be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say warm up properly , specially the muscles you are working on. Start with low weights and then gradually add weights.